# Local iOS-Android zeroconf ad-hoc networking

Tags: android, ios, networking, cross-platform, zeroconf

## The Desired Functionality:

User A is running your app on an Android or iOS device.  User A can automatically find and communicate with other nearby (< 20 meters?) users B and C (**Cross-Platform**), whether they're running Android or iOS, and without any of the users having an internet connection (**Offline**).

I believe this is a commonly desired functionality, and having a definitive answer to this question would be a great boon to the mobile development community.

### Further requirements/things you'd like to have, in order of importance:

- **Single Codebase** (or at least sharing 90+% of code) for Android and iOS, e.g. through Xamarin or something similar.
- Automatically choose the best (perhaps going down a list of preference) signal to use, e.g. choosing WiFi direct or bluetooth (similar to AllJoyn, Multipeer)
- Use only **Free** (or free for certain classes of user) libraries

## The Question:

How to achieve the desired functionality?

#### Sub-question 1

Is it even possible?

**Answer**: YES.  Apps like Firechat and Spaceteam do it, therefore it must be possible.

## Rejected Possibilities:

**Multipeer**: iOS only, doesn't achieve **Cross-Platform**.

**Alljoyn**: iOS bindings are Objective-C only, doesn't achieve **Single Codebase**.

**Mono.Zeroconf**: [Supposedly would require separate platform implementations](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17015/cross-platform-zeroconf), so don't achieve **Single Codebase**?

**Open Garden SDK**: Would be a great solution, except it doesn't actually exist yet.

I've been researching this topic for several days now, and I haven't been able to find a definitive answer. Part of it is probably that people use so many different terms like mesh networking, ad-hoc networking, zeroconf, DNS-SD, etc., which makes it difficult to search.

If you're interested in some of the research I did on stackoverflow and elsewhere, here are [some  notes and links](http://pastebin.com/CuqUmgjK) (I'm limited in the number of links I put directly in this post).

Comment: If you really want single codebase you can use Alljoyn with Unity.

Comment: I just tried a brief test with Firechat and it looks like it doesn't send messages between iOS and Android devices unless they are both connected to a wifi or cellular network. That is, the two devices don't connect directly. However, this was a quick and dirty test. I like to see if other people have the same experience.

Comment: Any updates on this? Really interested in a solution.

Comment: I was never able to find a solution to this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but I would highly recommend Xamarin with the library ZeroConf which is native and has Xamarin support.

https://github.com/onovotny/Zeroconf

It works great and that gets you close to your unified codebase with a native and uniform way of discovering other ZeroConf devices.

**Edit:** It looks like the ZeroConf library only supports subscribing to ZeroConf services and not publishing also and I think you will need publishing as well.  But it seems other users have requested it so it seems like a feature they will be adding.